# Что означает слово "мол"?

Tags: значение-слов

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что означает слово "мол" в этой фразе.
"Откинувшись на спинку скамьи, он за спиною профессора замигал Бездомному -- не противоречь, мол, ему, -- но растерявшийся поэт этих сигналов не понял."

Comment: На современный "русский язык" слово "мол" в этой фразе переводится словом "типа".

Answer (score 11):

МОЛ - усечённая форма слова МОЛВИЛ, употребляется в значении СЛОВНО МОЛВИЛ, ДЕСКАТЬ.

Ср.:" Откинувшись на спинку скамьи, он за спиною профессора замигал Бездомному- не противоречь, *мол[вил],* ему, - но растерявшийся поэт этих сигналов не понял."

Answer (score 9):

МОЛ, вводн. сл. Разг. Указывает на то, что приводимые слова являются передачей чужой речи, чужого мнения или высказаны самим говорящим ранее.

Здесь слово "мол" , скорее всего, означает, что мысль говорящего, передаваемая знаками, в словесной форме имеет такое содержание.

Answer (score 7):

Aleksandr Moretti, "мол" здесь вводное слово, которое не сказывается на значении фразы, а только подчеркивает, что написанное не дословное изложение сказанного, а лишь передача общего смысла. Поскольку Берлиоз не говорит вообще ничего, а лишь "стреляет" глазами, то "мол" в общем-то ничего и не добавляет к фразе, а лишь помогает читателю понять, какие слова и действия относятся к автору текста, а какие принадлежат героям.

Слово родственно "молва", "молвить", не путать с омонимом-существительным **"мол"**.

Answer (score 1):

Синонимы слова *мол*: говорить, дескать. Если не *мол* (наилучший вариант), то в этом случае подходит только *дескать*, т.к. речь идёт о мимике, жесте, т.е. невербальной передаче мысли.

Answer (score 1):

Слово "мол" является устаревшим синонимом слов "речь" и "язык". Слова-производные от слова "мол": молва, молчание, молитва и т. д. В скандинавских языках, несмотря на их германизацию, это слово осталось. Например: норск мол , данск мол (норвежский язык, датский язык). Несогласен также, что слово "мол" (морской термин) — заимствование с итальянского. Сколько можно унижаться? Мол отходит от берега, напоминая язык.